# How can I change my JavaFx's buttons to look exactly like this?

Tags: java, macos, javafx, jpanel, computer-science

[image]

[2]: Below is a piece of what I've done so far. Can't seem to get it to look    like the pic that I've attached.

```
  gp.getColumnConstraints().addAll(rc, rc1, rc2);
            gp.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
            gp.add(prev, 0, 0);
            gp.add(search, 1, 0);
            gp.add(next, 2, 0);

            Button add = new Button("Add + ");
            add.setPrefSize(75, 10);
            add.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    if (!fNameFld.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        Contact c = new Contact(fNameFld.getText().toString(), numF.getText().toString(),
                                emailf.getText().toString());
                        contact.add(c);
                        i = contact.indexOf(c);
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                }
            });

            Button edit = new Button("Edit * ");
            edit.setPrefSize(75, 10);
            edit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
```

Comment: Why don't you use `FXML` with `SceneBuilder`? Makes GUIs in `JavaFX` such a breeze.

Comment: With what exactly do you have an issue? The layout, the styling, the font, the text, ...?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a GridPane for this.  In fact, I’m pretty sure a GridPane alone can’t do what you want.

You can make a center-aligned HBox for each row, and put those rows into a single VBox:

```
Collection<HBox> buttonRows = Arrays.asList(
    new HBox(6, previous, search, next),
    new HBox(6, add, edit, remove),
    new HBox(6, clear, quit));
buttonRows.forEach(hbox -> hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER));

VBox buttonPane = new VBox(12);
buttonPane.getChildren().addAll(buttonRows);
```

You should get rid of all calls to `setPrefSize`.  Your buttons are perfectly capable of defining their own sizes.  If you want to give them larger internal margins, set their [-fx-label-padding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled) CSS properties.